# MVC razor format to postback viewmodel using groupby

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have the following viewModel:

```
public class VehiclesViewModel
    {
        public IList<Vehicle> Vehicles{ get; set; }
    }
```

Vehicle is:

```
public class Vehicle
{
  public Owner Owner { get; set; }
  public Make Make { get; set; }
  public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now in a razor view:

```
    @model VehiclesViewModel

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>Make</th>
          <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    @for(int i=0; i<Model.Vehicles.Count; i++)
    {

        <tr>
          <td>@Vehicle[i].Owner</td>
          <td>@Vehicle[i].Make</td>
          <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Vehicles[i].Status)</td>
        </tr>

    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So now I have a view I can display and alter the status for a vehicle and post it back to the controller no problem.

However I now have a new requirement to display the vehicles on the page grouped by the Owner of the vehicle. So I came up with:

```
@model VehiclesViewModel

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Make</th>
      <th>Model</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
@foreach(var vehicleGroup in @Model.Vehicles.GroupBy(x => x.Owner.Name))
{
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">@vehicleGroup.First().Owner.Name</td>
  </tr>
  foreach(var vehicle in vehicleGroup)
  {

       <tr>
         <td>@vehicle.Make.Name</td>
         <td>Need to provide a way to edit the status here</td>
       </tr>

  }
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that now I have this foreach syntax instead of for I don't know how to write and editor for the status.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach(var vehicleGroup in Model.Vehicles.GroupBy(x => x.Owner.Name))
{
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">@vehicleGroup.First().Owner.Name</td>
    </tr>

     foreach(var vehicle in vehicleGroup)
     {
         <tr>
              <td> @vehicle.Make.Name  </td>
              <td> @Html.EditorFor(m => vehicle.Status) </td>
         </tr>    
     }
}
```

However, I would suggest grouping your list inside your controller instead of view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use a simple input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="vehicle-@vehicle.Id"value="@vehicle.Status" />
```